# How to find all time periods in which there is overlap in a Python DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

my df is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Anne','Anne','Anne','Anne','Anne','Anne','Anne','Anne','Anne','Anne','Anne','Anne',
                           'Bob','Bob','Bob','Bob','Bob','Bob','Bob','Bob','Bob','Bob','Bob','Bob'],
               
               "start":["2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-04-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-06-01", "2019-07-01", "2019-08-01", "2019-09-01", "2019-10-01", "2019-11-01", "2019-12-01",  
                        "2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-04-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-06-01", "2019-07-01", "2019-08-01", "2019-09-01", "2019-10-01", "2019-11-01", "2019-12-01"],
               
                 "end":["2019-01-31", "2019-02-28", "2019-03-31", "2019-04-30", "2019-05-31", "2019-06-30", "2019-07-31", "2019-08-31", "2019-09-30", "2019-10-31", "2019-11-30", "2019-12-31",
                        "2019-01-31", "2019-02-28", "2019-03-31", "2019-04-30", "2019-05-31", "2019-06-30", "2019-07-31", "2019-08-31", "2019-09-30", "2019-10-31", "2019-11-30", "2019-12-31"],
                 
                "percentage":[1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12,
                              1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12]})

# insert "wrong" row
df.loc[len(df.index)] = ['Anne', "2019-01-15", "2019-02-15", 1/12] 

df.start = df.start.apply(pd.to_datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d")
df.end   = df.end.apply(pd.to_datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

I now want to find all rows of the same user of which there is an overlapping period. In my code example above there is only one overlap. The overlap is for Anne in the periods:

- 2019-01-01 till 2019-01-31
- 2019-02-01 till 2019-02-31
- 2019-01-15 till 2019-02-15

How do I return the indices of the rows of which there is overlap per user?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) rows by difference of end and start datetimes, add counter timedeltas by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to `start` column, last check duplicates by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and aggregate [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) for check if at leastone value match, last filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.end.sub(df.start).dt.days + 1)].copy()
df1['start'] += pd.to_timedelta(df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), 'd')

df1 = df[df1.duplicated(['Name','start'], keep=False).groupby(level=0).any()]
print (df1)
    Name      start        end percentage
0   Anne 2019-01-01 2019-01-31       1/12
1   Anne 2019-02-01 2019-02-28       1/12
24  Anne 2019-01-15 2019-02-15       1/12
```